# fading out a Javascript error message

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a error message that pops up whenever a form element does not validate. However, for some reason the error message does not fade out.

html:

```
<div class="span6">
  <p id="error-message"></p>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
if (response.error) 
{
    $('#error-message').addClass('alert alert-success').html("The charge was successful. Thanks for choosing Somii!");
        $("#error-message").fadeOut(3000);
}
```

Comment: Why are you mixing jQuery and native javascript?

Comment: if you open firebug on your browser and then console, do you see any errors?

Comment: @helion3 what difference does that make? JQuery is plain old javascript under the hood.

Comment: the .setTimeout function is jQuery?

Comment: @jeremyjjbrown I know I just meant he's duplicating efforts. He uses `document.getElementById("error-message")` in one line, and then `$('#error-message')` in the next

Comment: @helion3 I agree. jQuery makes traditional JavaScript look so bad when they're next to one another.

Comment: The first three lines could be combined to `$('#error-message').addClass('alert alert-danger').html(response.error.message);`

Comment: "the .setTimeout function is jQuery?" no that is plain javascript, the expressions with $(...) are JQuery.

Comment: well then, is there a jQuery function for fading out a window?

Comment: @Ryan Fading out a window..or an element? Because what's wrong with `$(element).fadeOut()`?

Comment: @remyabel i added that to my code above but it still not fading out

Comment: I dropped the code in a fiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/Dw24U/](http://jsfiddle.net/Dw24U/) and it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Once the error message fades out, it will never be seen. You have to make it visible again.

```
$("#error-message").show();
```

See my test fiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/JohnnyWorker/SC7Zm/. Press "Fire" to trigger.

It is working on my Chrome and IE10.